# Why are two buttons constrained with a ZERO distance between them, not flush?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsview

I have read in numerous places that constraints in Cocoa AutoLayout act on the visual bounds of the control/view in question so the below is perplexing (2me):

In Xcode IB, I add/drag two (`push button`) buttons to a view (one underneath the other) and constrain them such that they have zero distance between themselves vertically. I expect two buttons that are flush against one another in the vertical direction.

The result is two buttons that DO have a small difference/space between them which can be verified visually or by looking at the alignment rectangle values in Xcode. In this instance the additional distance between them appears to be 1 point.

[image: taken in Xcode 6]

Below is a screenshot of the constraints amongst the simple view hierarchy:

[image: view hierarchy and constraints]

Further, confirming the above, when you change the constant in the constraint to -1, the two buttons appear flush with one another.

[image: buttons with vertical difference of -1.0]

The above is on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).

Stranger still, in my actual application (the above is just a test case for the SO question) when I stack many `NSButton` vertically (programmatically and not via IB) I need to provid a constraint of -4.0 between them (as opposed to the -1.0 above) to make them flush. The bezelStyle for this button is as follows (Swift):

```
        self.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.RoundedBezelStyle
```

[Although it doesn't make sense, I would be much more comfortable if it were uniformly -1.0 needed to make them flush!]

UPDATE I:

I think I have found why my application is behaving differently to the test example. I have used a `NSBezelStyle.RoundedBezelStyle` in code and set its height to be 24.0; various things point to this button style/type needing to have a fixed height (see IB where the height parameter is greyed out and fixed at 21.0 and cannot be changed!) The difference between 24 and 21 is 3.0 which is exactly what we are seeing is the difference in main application constraints -4.0 relative to rest example required -1.0

The moral of the story: don't use `RoundedBezelStyle` outside certain usage scenarios where variable height is needed! PostScript: RoundedRectBezelStyle seems to suffer the same malady!

That still leaves the question of why certain buttons in the test example are not flush with a constraint of -1.0 being required...

UPDATE II:

Further testing shows that I get different results depending on which "type" of button I choose. In code this would be linked to the `bezelStyle` property of the button.

1. The gradient button sits flush with a constraint of zero between buttons
2. The textured button seems to need to need a +1.0 constraint between buttons to avoid overlap
3. Most of the other buttons (especially those with rounded bezel styles) seem to need constraint of -1.0 between themselves to be flush

REVISED QUESTION (based on my findings):

Are the above intentional from Apple (is there some logical/rational explanation) OR are they bugs? 
If the above is true, is it bad practise to code my user-interface (a spreadsheet-like grid) with these fudges for "flushness" built-in to how I layout my view?

Comment: Can you show us the constraints you are using to create the above example?

Comment: Question amended with constraints.

Comment: As an experiment, you can try setting a button's bottom to the top of a custom view that just fills with a solid color and, similarly, a button's top to the bottom of a custom view. The custom view's alignment rect will be the same as its frame. This will verify that, in Yosemite, a button's alignment rect simply doesn't exactly match its visual extent and make it clear on which side the "error" occurs. On Mavericks, there's no space between a button and a custom view. If there is on Yosemite, you can treat it like a bug and work around it or just accept that that's what Apple intends.

Answer (score 1):

How a view lays out in regards of it's bounds is up to the view itself.

What you have seen is the style of the button not covering then entire frame set up by autolayout. That is correct behaviour.

Comment: Is the behaviour you describe related to `alignmentRectInsets` and/or other related methods. If so, should I be overriding said methods to achieve my desired behaviour of "flushness" with AutoLayout?

Comment: You could do that, but that would require subclassing NSButton. Also there if the alignment inset has some non-zero value, it is due to how it draws it's content, so I would advise against changing it.

Comment: I have subclassed `NSButton` in my code and I have overridden `alignmentRectInsets` and this appears to allow buttons to stack on top of one another in a flush manner. Apple had hardcoded the value of this particular alignmentRectInset to (2,3,2,2) - what if they made a mistake?